# Omit weekends and/or holidays in days to complete formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2013

Is there a way to not include weekends and or holidays in an Excel formula involving dates? Example:

```
=Q2-Q1
```

(a date in `q2` minus a date in `q1` = so many days) Excluding weekends & holidays?

Answer (score 10):

### WORKDAY

The function `WORKDAY` is used to calculate the date a certain amount of work days before or after the start date - [information here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/WORKDAY-function-f764a5b7-05fc-4494-9486-60d494efbf33)

> **Syntax**
>
> WORKDAY(start_date, days, [holidays])
>
> The WORKDAY function syntax has the following arguments:
>
> Start_date - Required. A date that represents the start date.
>
> Days - Required. The number of nonweekend and nonholiday days before
>   or after start_date. A positive value for days yields a future date; a
>   negative value yields a past date.
>
> Holidays - Optional. An optional list of one or more dates to exclude
>   from the working calendar, such as state and federal holidays and
>   floating holidays. The list can be either a range of cells that
>   contain the dates or an array constant of the serial numbers that
>   represent the dates.

Example usage:

`=WORKDAY(A2,A3,A4:A6)` - Where A2 is your start date, A3 is the amount of days from this date you wish to add or subtract, and A4:A6 each contain a holiday date to exclude

---

### NETWORKDAYS

Alternatively, the function `NETWORKDAYS` is used to calculate the amount of work days between two dates - [information here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NETWORKDAYS-function-48e717bf-a7a3-495f-969e-5005e3eb18e7)

> **Syntax**
>
> NETWORKDAYS(start_date, end_date, [holidays])
>
> The NETWORKDAYS function syntax has the following arguments:
>
> Start_date - Required. A date that represents the start date.
>
> End_date - Required. A date that represents the end date.
>
> Holidays - Optional. An optional range of one or more dates to
>   exclude from the working calendar, such as state and federal holidays
>   and floating holidays. The list can be either a range of cells that
>   contains the dates or an array constant of the serial numbers that
>   represent the dates.

Example usage:

`=NETWORKDAYS(A2,A3,A4:A6)` - Where A2 is your start date, A3 is your end date, and A4:A6 contain holiday dates you wish to exclude.

---

### .INTL

In case you need this to work in a situation where weekends are not defined the same way (Saturday and Sunday), both of these formulas have a `.INTL` function, where they also take a `Weekend` argument as the third argument. ***Note*** - This is only supported in Excel 2010+. Information on [WORKDAY.INTL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/WORKDAY-INTL-function-a378391c-9ba7-4678-8a39-39611a9bf81d) and [NETWORKDAYS.INTL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NETWORKDAYS-INTL-function-a9b26239-4f20-46a1-9ab8-4e925bfd5e28).

This argument would be an integer, referring to these options:

```
Weekend number  Weekend days
1 (default)     Saturday, Sunday
2               Sunday, Monday
3               Monday, Tuesday
4               Tuesday, Wednesday
5               Wednesday, Thursday
6               Thursday, Friday
7               Friday, Saturday
11              Sunday only
12              Monday only
13              Tuesday only
14              Wednesday only
15              Thursday only
16              Friday only
17              Saturday only
```

This would affect the formulas above as such, specifying `Monday only` as your "weekend":

`=WORKDAY.INTL(A2,A3,12,A4:A6)`

and

`=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(A2,A3,12,A4:A6)`

Comment: NETWORKDAYS is the command I was looking for. Thank you very much for your help